# Entity Framework condition for bool to seperate active and inactive into classes not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do the following:
Map a class->Applicants to 2 subclasses ->ActiveApps and InactiveApps in Entity Framework 5.
The field in Applicants is a BIt mapped to a Boolean (IsActive);
I subclass the ActiveApps from Applicants and InactiveApps from Applicants.

I set a condition on both of them :

IsActive = True

IsActive =False

I have tried moving the IsActive column, deleting it, changing to =1 or 0 respectively.

I keep getting all kinds of error messages (though it still compiles).

Does anyone know how to do to set a condition for a boolean without actually getting errors on build?

Comment: Is the bit field all that differentiates the Active and InActive applicants?

Comment: Yes.That is in this case.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just filter the records into lists based on this field? `var activeApps = ctx.Applicants.Where(a => a.IsActive);`?  The same would be done for inactive.

Also, can you provide some errors you are getting?

Comment: I can do that but I am trying to use the conceptual mapping to make better semantics. I have more complex examples than this but I thought this was a non brainer subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I can fix this but it is too ugly for practical use. If you add any new entities to EDMX then it goes haywire.

What you do:

Set condition BoolField=0

Then 
Add default to Schema section for the scalar conditional item if there is none

Remove condition column from Conceptual model of subclass

Remove column from EntityTypeMapping of parent

Basic Take Home Message: Not quite ready for primetime in EF 5, imho.
You are better off just using views and not getting the inheritance.